# Not able to pre-select mat radio button on HTML page in Angula6

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, radio-button

There is a new requirement to include radio button input in an angular 6 application.There are two pages: Request and Approve. The user enters the value in request page and submit the request. Approver should open the request on approve page and should able to see all the details entered by requester.All the other values are showing in approver's page but radio button is not getting pre-slected on the basis on value provided on requester page.

Note: we need to store responses on both the pages separately for database entries.

The value for request.requestPurpose is coming up correctly and is displayed above radio buttons. I have use ng-checked too but it didn't work.Also, when I am using simply [checked]="true" for any particular radio button , it is not working for the same.

```
<h3>{{request.requestPurpose}}</h3>
<h4>{{request.dispensePurpose}}</h4>
<mat-radio-group required name="purpose" [(ngModel)]="request.dispensePurpose">
  Please select the request purpose :<br >
   <mat-radio-button value="Manufacturing"  *ngIf="request.reevaluationDate" [checked]="request.requestPurpose==='Manufacturing'" >Manufacturing stuff</mat-radio-button ><br>
    <mat-radio-button value="Manufacturing" [checked]="request.requestPurpose==='Manufacturing'" >Manufacturing and cleaning stuff</mat-radio-button><br>
    <mat-radio-button value="Development" [checked]="request.requestPurpose==='Development'">Dev is in progress</mat-radio-button><br>
    <mat-radio-button value="Testing" [checked]="request.requestPurpose==='Testing'">testing is being done</mat-radio-button><br>
    <mat-radio-button value=" " [checked]="request.requestPurpose===' '">None of the above apply to this request</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

The button should be pre-checked on the basis on value stored in request.requestPurpose.

Answer (score 0):

I waited for the answere but didn't get one.?However, i was able to figure out the solution.

While using [(ngmodel)] it is not possible to use [checked] attribute, so we can handle it in .ts file.

In  my case i used following to check a radio button by default on the basis of value in request.requestPurpose :

request.dispensePurpose=request.requestPurpose